# How to add/remove DOM elements in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to show simple message modal dialogs (bootstrap modal dialogs).

The dialog is a piece of HTML:

```
<div class="dlg">.....</div>
```

How can I add this piece of HTML into the DOM tree when I want to show a dialog and remove it when dialog is closed?

Obviously, this should be done in a **directive**. But how can I call the **'ShowDialog()**' method of a directive in a controller's button click handler?

Comment: Ui-bootstrap does that through its `$modal` service which exposes the `open` function. In the end a function of second servive `$modalStack` will do `body = angular.element.find('body')` and then `body.append(CUSTOM HTML)`. Have a look at teir code:https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js

Comment: The simplest way is to use `ng-if` and to switch the condition to true/false.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, pass through $modal in your DI, check out the example: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                        </script>

                        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
                        </div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};
```